Anyone managed to get a Dynamic Rule working that requires a user two be a member of two already existing intune groups?
I am trying to create a dynamic rule for a group in Intune to add users who are members of two other, existing groups. I've been trying to do this with the memberof function, but with no success.
Basically I need a rule that says to be a member of Group 1, you must be a member of both Group A and Group B.
I've tried this rule:
user.memberof -any (group.objectId -in ['76d69507-e49e-4d72-abcd-dc8e514eef92']) and user.memberof -any (group.objectId -in ['62a1a421-f684-4091-abcd-0b81be99827b'])
Which passes the syntax check, but fails to populate any members. I've tested both of the group requests individually, and both work.
user.memberof -any (group.objectId -in ['76d69507-e49e-4d72-abcd-dc8e514eef92']) - Works
user.memberof -any (group.objectId -in ['62a1a421-f684-4091-abcd-0b81be99827b']) - Works
so it must be something to do with combining the rules, but I can't figure out what else I am doing wrong.
Sadly, the validate rules function in intune, doesn't seem to work with memberof, as it always shows as failed even if I am testing someone who is in the group membership list.
